# Upper bound for weak edge colorings?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285232/different-form-of-edge-coloring).

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph such that every vertex has degree at least $2$. Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a map $c:E \to \{1,\ldots, n\}$ is said to be a *weak coloring* if for every $v\in V$ the edges adjacent to $v$ do not all have the same color. More formally, we want the restriction $c|_{E(v)}$ to be non-constant, where $E(v) = \{e\in E: x\in e\}$. (Is there a name for this kind of edge-coloring?)

Is there some positive integer $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such every graph $G=(V,E)$ with minimal degree $2$ has a weak edge coloring $c:E\to\{1,\ldots,n_0\}$? If yes, what is the smallest such integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers to the previous question, the only connected graphs which require more than two colors are odd cycles, which are trivially weak 3-colorable. Therefore, $n_0 = 3$ always suffices.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I misread that in the old answers. I assume your argument also shows $n_0 = 3$ for infinite graphs? - Very nice argument!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Euler tour is not universally present in infinite graphs with even degrees. It seems plausible that $n_0 = 3$ holds in infinite case, but I'm not yet sure how to prove it.